# How to model a driven wheel with no slip

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, dynamics, mechanical

I'm working on a design problem, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to model the torque needed to drive a bike tire at a set acceleration.

Let's say I have a tire with normal force between tire and ground *Fn*, coefficient of static friction between tire and ground *u*, and diameter *d*.

What is the necessary axle torque to drive the tire at desired linear acceleration *a* from standstill without slipping? How great can *a* be if you want to avoid slip?

Also, the problem doesn't give me a tire mass or moment of inertia. Is this problem possible without those?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the road level, because no information on slope is given, the maximum force before slipping is $F_{max}= F_n* \mu =mg\mu  $

Then the torque will be $  \tau = mg\mu D/2=I \alpha$

assuming the mass of the wheel is concentrated at the perimeter its

$$ I= mD^2/4 $$

$$\alpha = \frac{mD^2/4}{mg \mu D/2}$$ $$ \alpha=<\frac{D}{2g\mu} $$

Comment: I think $F_n$ should be $m*g$, not just $m$.

Comment: @am304, yes you're right. I have modified my answer.